# How to get and work with the FONT property of an ANONYMOUS CONTROL?

Tags: delphi, object-type, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, in a VCL Application, using the `OnMessage` event-handler of a `TApplicationEvents` component, I increase the font-size of the right-clicked Control:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ThisControl: TControl;
begin
  if (Msg.Message = WM_RBUTTONDOWN) then
  begin
    ThisControl := FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True);
    CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: RIGHTCLICK!', ThisControl.Name);
    if ThisControl is TLabel then
      TLabel(ThisControl).Font.Size := TLabel(ThisControl).Font.Size + 1
    else if ThisControl is TCheckBox then
      TCheckBox(ThisControl).Font.Size := TCheckBox(ThisControl).Font.Size + 1;
    // ETC. ETC. ETC.! :-(
  end;
end;
```

This is an extremely INEFFICIENT way to make this work for all Control Types because I would have to enumerate all existent Control Types, as `TControl` does not have a `TFont` property.

A better way would be to get the `TFont` property of the control without having to ask for the TYPE and then having to TYPECAST the Control.

But HOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redeclare the type, you get access to the protected properties of the class.
Nowadays you do that with an interposer class, but I'm still used to the old ways.
You might have to add a check, if it turns out that a particular control bombs, when you do something with the font. It has always worked for me so far.

```
type
  TCrackControl = class(TControl);

procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ThisControl: TCrackControl;
begin
  if (Msg.Message = WM_RBUTTONDOWN) then
  begin
    ThisControl := TCrackControl(FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True));
    CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: RIGHTCLICK!', ThisControl.Name);
    If assigned(ThisControl.Font) then
    ThisControl.Font.Size := ThisControl.Font.Size + 1;
   
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write: `if System.TypInfo.IsPublishedProp(ThisControl, 'Font') then ThisControl.Font.Size := ThisControl.Font.Size + 1;`

Comment: No, since `.Font` of `TCrackControl` is always published - that's the whole point of defining that class and casting `TControl` to it.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I think you are wrong here. This method doesn't cause any properties to be published. The only thing it does is that it makes the protected members accessible, because `TCrackControl` is declared in the same unit. (So `strict protected` members cannot be accessed this way.)

Comment: Well, I could declare TWO Control variables, one of type `TControl` and one of type `TCrackControl`. Then the code would be: `if System.TypInfo.IsPublishedProp(ThisNoCrackControl, 'Font') then ThisCrackControl.Font.Size := ThisCrackControl.Font.Size + 1;`

Comment: (In any case, the cast to `TCrackControl` is missing in the A.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand What cast do you mean exactly?

Comment: `ThisControl := TCrackControl(FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True));`

Comment: I suppose you mean: `ThisCrackControl := TCrackControl(FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True));` In this case I could use the TWO Control variables.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote! :) The code in this A won't compile unless the `TCrackControl` cast is added.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Then how would you implement the needed CHECK proposed by @RenateSchaaf? Because the Answer code would get an AV if the Control has no `Font` property!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I live in a past where `strict protected` doesn't exist (yet). Although `TControl` defines `.Font` and it lurks there until the well-known classes of the controls (i.e. `TCheckBox`) publish it I know there are controls which never publish it (i.e. `TSplitter`). If those can also occur in OP's event the question is then: will it hurt?

Comment: @user1580348: I didn't address that part. My only intention was to remark that the code given in this answer doesn't even compile, unless the change I mentioned is made. Surely Renate Schaaf only forgot that cast. (**Upd: Yes, now that was edited in.**) // Every `TControl` has a `Font` property, but of course it might be `nil`. Thus, you can do `if Assigned(ThisControl.Font)` to test. // But even if a control has a font and it is protected, it might not like that you tamper with it. So your initial suggestion of using `IsPublishedProp` sounds good to me.

Comment: Also, please notice that the statement `No, since .Font of TCrackControl is always published` made by another user above is incorrect.

Comment: @RenateSchaaf Can you please add that check proposed by @AndreasRejbrand: `if Assigned(ThisControl.Font)` to your answer?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks, I corrected it. I thought it would compile without the type cast. I also added the check for assigned, hope that's all the check it needs.

Comment: Actually, the font of a TControl is always assigned, see VCL.Controls.TControl.Create.

Comment: @RenateSchaaf: Yes, it probably is. Still, I'd probably keep the `Assigned` test in any case. It is essentially free, and who knows -- maybe a future version of VCL acts differently, maybe `FFont` is set to `nil` later on, etc.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand that will never happen. The VCL is too mature to make such a fundamental change to its behavior like that.